# My photo field don't save selection when I edit my post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

The problem occurs when I edit a post in my back-office. All the belong_to table don't save the informations were saved when I create the post.

I don't find solution on the web. I'm not an experiment dev so I don't now where I must look for.

My upload_file :

```
require "image_processing/mini_magick"

class ImageUploader < Shrine
 plugin :processing # allows hooking into promoting
 plugin :versions   # enable Shrine to handle a hash of files
 plugin :delete_raw # delete processed files after uploading

 process(:store) do |io, context|
   original = io.download
   pipeline = ImageProcessing::MiniMagick.source(original)

   size_200 = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(200, 200)
   size_300 = pipeline.resize_to_limit!(300, 300)

   original.close!

   { original: io, moyen: size_300, small: size_200 }
 end
end
```

My model :

```
has_one :photo, as: :attachable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo
```

My controller :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Admin::ActualitiesController < Admin::AdminController
  before_action :set_actuality, only: %i[show edit update destroy]

  def index
    @actualities = Actuality.order('id DESC').page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def new
    @actuality = Actuality.new
    @actuality.build_photo
  end

  def edit
  end

  def show; end

  def create
    @actuality = Actuality.new(actuality_params)

    if @actuality.save
      redirect_to :show, notice: ''
    else
      render :new, notice: ''
    end
  end

  def update
    if @actuality.update(actuality_params)
      redirect_to :show, notice: ''
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @actuality.destroy
    redirect_to admin_actualities_path, notice: ''
  end

  private

  def set_actuality
    @actuality = Actuality.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def actuality_params
    params.require(:actuality).permit(:title, :body, :apercu, :meeting, photo_attributes: [:photo])
  end
end
```

And in my form :

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :photo do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.input :photo, as: :hidden %>
    <%= ff.input :photo, as: :file %>
<% end %>
```

If you have any solutions, I'm here !
Thanks !

Comment: Post the entire controller. Are the `actuality_params` being used in the `update` action properly?

Comment: I edit my post whit my entire controller. Thanks

Comment: Up please! I don't find the solution yet

Comment: Is that your entire controller? No `create` or `update` methods at all?

Comment: Sorry i make a mistake. It isn't the admin controller. I edit it in the morning

Comment: @JayDorsey it's ok my controller is edit with the good one. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Up ! I realy don't understand where is the problem